# ¿Como puedo manipular una Tabla de wikipedia con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Verán, quiero utilizar la siguiente tabla de wikipedia en mi codigo [image: "]

Me he metido en el modo edición y me he encontrado el siguiente codigo. Que ni siquiera sé cual es el lenguaje utilizado

[image: Sé que no es la forma de mostrar el codigo pero es que no me dejaba meter todo el código no se por qué]

Sé que no es la forma de mostrar el codigo pero es que no me dejaba meter todo el código no se por qué.

**Quiero poder manipular todos esos datos y si se puede que diariamente se vayan actualizando los datos** (aunque creo que eso ultimo seria para otro hilo)

*no importa si hay que utilizar librerias*

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hiciste fue revisar el modo de edición de wikipedia que es un modo amigable de editar la página sin conocer HTML. Pero para acceder a la información necesitas algo que entienda HTML, como puede ser requests, selenium o la siguiente función de pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_html_table = pd.read_html("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Chile")
dfChile = raw_html_table[5]
print(dfChile)
```

Para actualizar diariamente va a depender de como diseñes tu programa, si haces un `time.sleep(86400)` dentro de un `while(1)`, si haces un programa pequeño y lo agregas al planificador del sistema operativo y también la actualización dependerá de como finalmente almacenes la información dentro de tu programa ¿diccionario? ¿una base de datos? ¿un objeto? La pregunta es demasiado amplia.